# How to transform this list of types with brigand?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have the following list of types:

```
using ComponentList = brigand::list<TransformComponent, ObjectComponent, BodyComponent>
```

How can I transform the previous list into a new list that would look like this:

```
using ComponentHandleList = brigand::list<entityx::ComponentHandle<TransformComponent>, entityx::ComponentHandle<ObjectComponent>, entityx::ComponentHandle<BodyComponent>>;
```

I basically want to generate a new list that has wrappers for every element in the previous list.
I tried doing it by using:

```
using ComponentHandleList = brigand::transform<ComponentList, AddComponentHandle<brigand::_1>>;
```

But I don't know much about meta-programming and failed to implement the `struct AddComponentHandle<>`, that would take a type `T` and convert it into `entityx::ComponentHandle<T>`. Brigand includes relevant [documentation](https://github.com/edouarda/brigand/wiki/Algorithms) about transforming a list of types by showing an example of converting every type `T` to `T*` by using `std::add_pointer<>`. Which is the same thing I want to do but going from `T` to `entityx::ComponentHandle<T>`. How can I convert the first list so it looks like the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <brigand/sequences/list.hpp>
#include <brigand/algorithms/transform.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

struct TransformComponent{};
struct ObjectComponent{};
struct BodyComponent{};
namespace entityx
{
    template <typename Component>
    struct ComponentHandle{};
}

using ComponentList = brigand::list<TransformComponent, ObjectComponent, BodyComponent>;

template <typename Comp>
using AddComponentHandle = entityx::ComponentHandle<Comp>;

template <typename Comp>
struct AddComponentHandle2
{
    using type = entityx::ComponentHandle<Comp>;
};

using ComponentHandleList = brigand::transform<ComponentList, brigand::bind<AddComponentHandle,brigand::_1>>;
using ComponentHandleList2 = brigand::transform<ComponentList, AddComponentHandle2<brigand::_1>>;


int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<ComponentHandleList,
                                brigand::list<
                                    entityx::ComponentHandle<TransformComponent>,
                                    entityx::ComponentHandle<ObjectComponent>,
                                    entityx::ComponentHandle<BodyComponent>
                                >
                  >::value
                 );
    static_assert(std::is_same<ComponentHandleList2,
                                brigand::list<
                                    entityx::ComponentHandle<TransformComponent>,
                                    entityx::ComponentHandle<ObjectComponent>,
                                    entityx::ComponentHandle<BodyComponent>
                                >
                  >::value
                 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the transformation using

```
template<typename, template<typename...> class>
struct apply {};

template<template<typename...> class T, template<typename...> class List, typename ... Ts>
struct apply<List<Ts...>, T> {
    using type = List<T<Ts>...>;
};
```

it can be used like this

```
template<typename...>
struct A {};

template<typename...>
struct B {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<apply<A<int, bool>, B>::type, A<B<int>, B<bool>>>::value);
}
```

Comment: My question wasn't very clear, I am not asking how to convert a list of types into a list of types with pointers. What I want to know is how can I convert a list of types into a list of a wrapper around a type, ex: List<int, bool> -> List<Wrapper<int>, Wrapper<bool>>

Comment: @BryanTriana fixed

Comment: How can I make this work if brigand::list is template<typename... T> struct list{} instead of the A struct you proposed which is template<typename...> struct A{}. Notice the T after ... which is the cause for conversion errors when using the brigand::list.

Comment: @BryanTriana it works with `template<typename... T> struct list{}` instead of A